# sysCall(Sys_gettid) return -1

Tags: ios, unix

I use sysCall(Sys_gettid) on iOS app, but return -1.

```
const char *elog_port_get_t_info(void) {
    static char cur_thread_info[10] = { 0 };

    snprintf(cur_thread_info, 10, "tid:%04ld", syscall(SYS_gettid));

    return cur_thread_info;
}
```

Comment: ios is not linux. Removed that tag.

Comment: You should check `errno` to see what made `syscall()` return an error. Maybe using `strerror()` or `perror()` to get a human-readable error message and not a cryptic numeric code.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `syscall` on iOS or macOS directly. The `gettid` call is meant to get the current thread ID. Depending on what you want to do there are several alternatives:

For example, you can query the thread ID using pthreads:

```
#include <pthread.h>
uint64_t tid;
pthread_threadid_np(NULL, &tid);
```

You could also make use of `NSThread`. Either use the pointer returned by `[NSThread currentThread]` or, probably better, make use of the [`threadDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsthread/1411433-threaddictionary?changes=_2__5&language=objc):

```
(untested)
NSString * identifier = thread.threadDictionary[@"myIDKey"];
if (identifier == nil) {
   identifier = [NSUUID UUID].UUIDString;
   thread.threadDictionary["myIDKey"] = identifier;
}
```